# Enlarge Auto-complete Text Box JQuery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have following definition of auto-complete list embedded with Search text box:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
    <font size="6px">
        Customer: 
        <ul id="autocomplete_customer" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a customer..." data-filter-theme="d"></ul>
    </font>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that Search text box size is very small. How can I enlarge it? may be some jquery or css trick?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after -

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div style='font-size:18px;padding-bottom:15px;'>Customer:</div> 
        <ul id="autocomplete_customer" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a customer..." data-filter-theme="d">
            <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
            <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>

$(function () {
    $('form input[data-type="search"]').css('height', '75px');
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rossmartin/Kkt4x/)